# Design a share, re-share functionality for a website, avoiding duplication

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

This is an interesting interview question that I found somewhere. To elaborate more:

> You are expected to design classes and data structures for some website such as facebook or linkedin where your activity can be shared and re-shared. Design should be such that it avoids redundancy and duplication.

While thinking of this problem I was stuck on "link vs copy" problem as discussed [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/optimal-database-design-regarding-functionality-of-letting-user-share-posts-by-o)

But since the problem states that duplication should be avoided I decided to go "link" way. This makes sharing/re-sharing easier but deleting very difficult. i.e. if the original user deletes their post all the shares should be deleted. (programmatically speaking all the objects on the pointing to the particular activity should be made null. And this is the difficult part here, i.e. to find all the pointing objects)

Comment: The traditional solution to the making all links null problem is the 404 error ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to *keep* the shares? The original user deletes
their post, fine, it's gone. But everyone who has linked to it should
not suddenly have it disappear on them.

This could be done the way Unix handles hard links. "Deleting" just
means removing one link to an object -- an inode, in Unix terms. You
don't remove the object itself until the link count is zero.

Comment: That could be a very political question-- if I say something I want to retract, should I be allowed to?  But then, once it's out there anyway, perhaps that would just give me a false sense of security?

Comment: @TomZych :  on facebook you can't keep shares once original user deletes them..thats where I derived the notion from.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious from the original specification that deletion should work as you describe.  It might be desired that when the original user deletes the item, it is not deleted elsewhere; in that case you don't necessarily need to track all references, just keep a reference count on each post, and remove it from the database only when the count hits zero.

If you do want the behavior you describe, it may be achievable by simply removing broken links as and when you encounter them, again relieving you of the need to track each reference.  The cost of tracking and updating every reference to every post is replaced with the comparable cost of one failed lookup for each referring page.  The latter case is simpler to implement, though, and the cost doesn't hit your server all at once.

In real life, I would implement all references as bidirectional anyway, because it's likely to be needed sooner or later as you add features.  For example, a "like" counter seems pretty simple, but to prevent duplicate votes you need to keep track of who has liked each item, and then if you want to remove their "like" when they delete their profile, you need to keep a list of each user's outbound "likes" too.

It takes a lot of database activity to implement something like Facebook...

Comment: @bobato : Your second point..i.e. removing the links as you encounter them, in this case if we take facebook example then removing the broken links on the profile as the user logs in(while loading their wall)..won't it slow down the loading time ? But I agree on most of your points and I agree that this design is a tradeoff between bidirectional references and load/delete time cost.

Comment: The cost of removing the item needn't slow down page loading. When the item fails to load, you just skip rendering it, and queue the database changes to be processed asynchronously.